# Disable Word/Sharepoint Integration

Tags: sharepoint, wss, webdav

I have a requirement to disable the integration between Sharepoint and Word in a project that I am working on. This requirement comes from the request that the user is able to edit the properties of the document but not edit the document itself.  The request has also been made to disable the Shared Workspace toolbar that appears when a document is open. The solution must exist on the server as some of the users are external. The users have also requested that they are able to use the Outlook/Sharepoint Integration.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: The problem here is that editing the properties *is* editing the document itself. They are directly linked. See http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2004/11/22/267846.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing they want to change some document properties, apply those as new field values and print - but not change the original.

Here are some ideas, not sure how useful they could be.

1) apply a password for editing the Word document - It may still allow changing properties & printing.

2) strip out doc the properties and put them in a sharepoint list, with the document itself as an attachement - the document then remains as read-only, but the properties are held separately

3) If your documents are in a list, Allow changes on the list, but demand changes be approved, so users only get to see their own changes, no-one else sees the changes they made. Changes will sit there pending approval.  Periodically you can go and reject any changes.

Comment: +1 for options 2 and 3. Option 1 wouldn't work for the reason you state.